# How to limit android app to a single instance?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an app that could be launched by a user or by the system (based on its main activity intent).  So, in some cases there might be two instances of the app running at the same time.

Is there a way to limit the app to a single instance?

Thanks.

Comment: "So, in some cases there might be two instances of the app running at the same time" -- that is not possible. There might be two instances of an *activity* running at the same time, but an activity is not an app. Look into [launch modes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) and other ways of managing your [task](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html).

Answer (score 3):

Add `android:launchMode= "singleInstance"` to your activity.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That is unlikely to be the best solution. Quoting [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode): "The other modes — `singleTask` and `singleInstance` — are not appropriate for most applications, since they result in an interaction model that is likely to be unfamiliar to users and is very different from most other applications. "

Comment: @CommonsWare what will be right way to not create multiple instance.

Comment: `singleTop` may suffice for the use case, perhaps in conjunction with `android:taskAffinity`. The question has very few details.

Comment: @Andrea Ebano singleInstance will not work for me because there is a possibility of two different activities from my app being visible on the list of recent applications.

Comment: @CommonsWare I've been using singleTop on the main activity.  However, this does not prevent the system from launching another instance of a given activity through a new intent.

Comment: @bdristan: "there is a possibility of two different activities from my app being visible on the list of recent applications" -- then you should be using `android:taskAffinity` to attempt to control the tasks that your activities go into. My guess is that you have bigger architectural problems that need to be addressed that is causing you to worry about this. This is akin to a Web developer trying to prevent users from having two tabs open onto the same Web site at the same time.